# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Vue.js with Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: vuejs2, asp.net-core-mvc

I am Creating a new Project Asp.net Core with Vue 
i am using boiler plate i have tried to run this command then i am getting this error that

> Object Reference to an instance of Object is not defined

```
dotnet new vuejs
```

and i getting this error

Comment: Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue? Do you mean run `dotnet new vuejs ` throw this error?

Comment: yes i mean the same Exact thing

Comment: For `dotnet new`, it will follow with template name, do you install `vuejs` template? How did you install it?